# Remove image from CListCtrl

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc

How can i remove image from ClistCtrl :

I am trying as below :

```
LVITEM item;
item.mask = LVIF_TEXT;
item.iItem = rowIndex;
item.iSubItem = 0;
item.pszText = L"";
item.state = 0;
item.stateMask = 0;
item.iImage = -1;
item.lParam = 0;

listCtrl.InsertItem(&item);
```

My CListCtrl has image list which is showing properly. How can i remove it?

Tried this :

```
  if (dataValue.at(0) == INVALID)
    {   
        listCtrl.InsertItem(rowIndex, L"", 0);
    }   
    else
    {
        LVITEM item = { 0 };
        item.mask = LVIF_TEXT | LVIF_IMAGE;
        item.iItem = rowIndex;
        item.pszText = L"Test";
        item.iImage = -1;
        listCtrl.SetItem(&item);
    }
```

Comment: Have you looked at [CListCtrl::DeleteItem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hfshke78.aspx#clistctrl__deleteitem)?

Comment: it doesn't work. It deletes texts and images all. I just need to remove the image

Comment: So, [SetItem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hfshke78.aspx#clistctrl__setitem) if you don't want to delete the whole item, but rather to update it. Did you even try looking at the documentation?

Comment: You can't have no image once images have been added. The way to do it is to have an empty image in your image list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `LVIF_IMAGE` to the mask if you want to remove the image:

```
LVITEM item = { 0 };
item.mask = LVIF_IMAGE;
item.iItem = rowIndex;
item.iImage = -1;
listCtrl.SetItem(&item);
```

If you don't use the right mask then the corresponding members are ignored.

From [LVITEM documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774760(v=vs.85).aspx):

> `LVIF_IMAGE`
>   The `iImage` member is valid or must be set.
>
> `LVIF_TEXT`
>   The `pszText` member is valid or must be set

Comment: actually it's a validation icon. in valid case there will be no image in the row just text in other cells. 
in invalid case there will be both image and text

Comment: if i use both item in mask both text and images are gone.

Comment: same it's actually hiding both text and image

Comment: I just tested it and it works. It's 5 lines of code, I don't know where you could be making a mistake.

Comment: can you see the edit code? The first condition is showing the image and text both. 
In else 
I need to show the text only.
But it's hiding both text and image.

Can you guess why?

Comment: Don't put `LVIF_TEXT | LVIF_IMAGE`. Use `LVIF_IMAGE` only. Just copy/paste the 5 lines from above.

Answer (score 1):

What i needed was to show a validation icon on invalid case and hide the icon in valid case :

```
if (dataValue.at(0) == INVALID)
  {   
    listCtrl.InsertItem(rowIndex, L"");
  }   
else
  {
    listCtrl.InsertItem(rowIndex, L"", -1);
  }
```

Looked to me only way to hide the image was setting a invalid image with -1 as 3rd param.

This is weird!!

Comment: Your question is clearly about modifying existing image item. You should have ask about "inserting item without image". `-1` is invalid image index, it fools the listview control. You should really use an icon which indicates invalid.